# Is trigger update existing records?

Tags: data-loader, field-update

I have one trigger that updates records. Now i just wanted to know if we update those records with data loader. The D M L Operation code would perform or not. Because i need to update few existing records, so i developed trigger. I hope this trigger fire when record modified. But i need to update all at a time.

Comment: Are you asking if the data loader (or youe ETL tool of choice) fires triggers?  If so, the answer is yes, they do.

Comment: Yeah it is data loader. So for data loader update trigger will fire right?

Comment: Correct, it will fire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Data Loader (or your ETL tool of choice) will fire triggers during mass data manipulations.

Comment: Can we import empty fields and update with empty data? Will it fire if we update with data. I hope it will be.

Comment: There is a setting in the data loader to insert null values.  This will insert empty data.